# Delphi FMX and Indy on OSX returns socket errors, but not on PC

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy

When I compile the following code with Windows as target, it loads the site fine, compiling it for OSX 10.12.x, Indy return a Socket Error # 54. On OSX 10.13 High Sierra, the same code works fine.
After days of trying, I just cant figure it out.

Does anybody has any clue for me?

I am using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

```
id:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
ssl:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(id);
id.IOHandler:=ssl;
id.HTTPOptions:=[hoWantProtocolErrorContent,hoNoProtocolErrorException];
id.RedirectMaximum:=5;
id.ReadTimeout:=30000;
id.HandleRedirects:=true;

ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions:=[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2,sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv23,sslvSSLv3];

s:=id.Get('https://www.fleurtygirl.net/');

ssl.Free;
id.free;
```

Comment: First off, stay away from `sslvSSLv2` and `sslvSSLv3`, as they are not secure and nobody uses them anymore. And you shouldn't be using `sslvSSLv23` in the `SSLVersions` property, either. Use only `sslvTLSv1` and later. That said, error 54 is "Connection reset by peer" which means the server is forcibly closing the connection on its end. Maybe it doesn't like your SSL/TLS handshake. Maybe it is just a bug in 10.12 (since it works in 10.13). Who knows. Without a stack trace leading up to the socket error, and a trace of the raw TCP traffic, there is really no way to answer this.

Comment: Its still the same. I installed openssl via brew and when executing openssl version, it shows 1.0.2p 14 Aug 2018, but delphi keep on loading libssl.0.9.8.dylib

Comment: Indy loads OpenSSL dynamically at runtime, attempting to load multiple variations of filenames until it finds a match. If the dylib files you want to use are not in the app's folder, you can use the `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function at app startup to tell Indy where they are located.

Comment: I compiled the libraries as 32 bit, it produced libssl.1.0.0.dylib and libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib. I copied them into the <app>/Contents/MacOS where I also found other libs, but it still wont load them. Then I renamed them to libssl.dylib and libcrypto.dylib, and again nothing. I cannot get it to load the libs. I then copied them to my user folder, and set the path to them with IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(), and the same again, they wont get loaded.

Comment: I also tried to load them manually via LoadLibrary, only the libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib could be loaded, the libssl.1.0.0.dylib fail also with LoadLibrary to load, and I have no clue why. My projects are not all not working anymore in macOS 10.12 and below due to this openssl thing.

Comment: Well, if calling `LoadLibrary()` directly fails, then obviously Indy will fail as well. You need to figure out why `LoadLibrary()` is failing. Could be a bad build, a missing dependency, etc. But you can't just rename the files, as libssl depends on libcrypto, and so depends on the original filename. Also, why are you using OpenSSL 1.0.0 and not 1.0.2?

Comment: I compiled now 1.0.2p, and both libs are created. Again, I can load libcrypto with LoadLibrary, but not libssl. The error for libssl is "No such file or directory", even the lib is there. I can test it also with FileExists() and its found, I can load the lib into a memorystream too, so its definitely there and I dont understand why I cant load it with LoadLibrary.

Comment: In which case, it is likely that a dependency that libssl requires is missing, not libssl itself

Comment: I think I figured it out. When compiling the libs, the path where they are created are hardcoded in the libs, and when moving them to my app folder for example, libssl is looking for libcrypto at the location where it was created, so I have no idea how I can bundle them because every mac will have a different location/path for the app.

Comment: sounds like a configuration error in the lib projects. You should ask the OpenSSL community about that.